# tapestry4 forward error

Tags: java, tapestry

anyone can decrypt below error and explain what cause this error?

http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/jrscSzhcW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Home page implementation is recursively throwing a [RedirectException](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4/tapestry/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry/RedirectException.html).

Open your Home class and figure out why you are causing redirection to the same page.

If you were to paste your code (Home.java) someone could help you further.

Comment: somehow the redirection is causing recursion. there may be 2 redirections happening, one on your home page, one in your authentication page but the recursion is definitely happening. i suggest you breakpoint the code in an IDE and figure it out for yourself because what you've posted is pretty hard to read and i don't think shows the full picture.